# How can get variable in callback in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var addComp;
function geocodeSearch(pt){
        gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
          var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
                         });
                      }

geocodeSearch(point[i]);
console.log(addComp);
```

How can I get addComp?I have tried,but get nothing.
I mean it could better return 'addComp'

Comment: The function `gc.getLocation` returns immediately and the callback function is run later, after the location has been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `addComp` is out of scope by the time you are trying to log it.

You could define it globally.

```
var addComp;
function geocodeSearch(pt) {
    gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs) {
        var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
    });
}
console.log(addComp);
```

Or you could move you you logging into the inner function

```
function geocodeSearch(pt) {
    gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs) {
        var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
        console.log(addComp);
    });
}
```

Comment: I mean it could better return 'addComp',I want to use it outside.

Comment: You could also wrap it in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to implement it like that, you could:

```
var globalAddComp;
function geocodeSearch(pt){
        gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
          globalAddComp = rs.addressComponents;
                         });
                      }
console.log(globalAddComp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define addComp outside the function so that it becomes a global variable. Try this:

```html
var addcomp;
function geocodeSearch(pt){
        gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
          addComp = rs.addressComponents;
                         });
                      }
console.log(addComp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function geocodeSearch(pt){
  gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
    var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
    console.log(addComp);
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to use this variable out of this function,but I just can't get it